# How to create a action for UIReturnKeyType.Done in UITextView in xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the UITextView keyboard return button in to Done button.

I need to close the keyboard when I press the Done button.

I have create a UITextView and change the return button in to Done button.

This is my code

```
PhotoTitle = new UITextView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, Editable = true,               AccessibilityIdentifier = "PhotoTitle", 
ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
}
```

The keyboard showing Done button successfully. if I press it just behave like return button.

And I can not find a particuler event for fire when tap on Done button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to keep remember that, *UITexiView is a scrollable UI widget*. So, when you change the keyboard's default *Return* key in to *Done* button, you are hiding the opportunity of go to new line inside your UITextView. Therefore my suggestion is, if you are using a UITextView and you need a *Done* button by keeping the default keyboard, you should add a UIToolBar on top of the keyboard where you can place the *Done* button.

Since I'm not aware of your real need, which may do not need go to a new line and just need to exit the keyboard when user tap on the Return/Done button, here how you need to do it.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        TextView.WeakDelegate = this;
    }

    [Export("textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:")]
    public bool ShouldChangeText(UITextView textView, NSRange range, string text) 
    {
        if (text.Equals("\n"))
        {
            TextView.ResignFirstResponder();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is quite easy actually subscribe to the `ShouldReturn` event of the `UITextField` with a delegate or anonymous method that will call ResignFirstResponder on the field.

You can check [this](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/input/keyboards/dismiss_the_keyboard/DismissKeyboard) example project that shows how to do it

```
this.txtDefault.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
textField.ResignFirstResponder();
return true;
};
```

Comment: Cann't we do this by using UITextView

Comment: Either is fine i guess if the event is present

Comment: event is not present with UITextView so any other way to do this with UITextView?

Comment: Have you checked the example in Github?